# Show an image when having the URL but not the path

Tags: html, image

The following link https://www.flickr.com/photos/39420315@N05/26406523594 is the URL of an image. I want to show it by using:

```
<img src="...">
```

How may I achieve that?

Comment: If this is directly related to Flickr links, you should read up on their FAQ found here: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/sln7319.html. It should explain to you how to get the direct link of images. It's the section called "Copy the image or get a direct URL to it".

Comment: "The owner has disabled downloading of their photos", meaning you will likely not be able to do this without inspect elementing the page and getting the direct link that way.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
<img src="https://www.flickr.com/photos/39420315@N05/26406523594">
```

The `<img>` tag expects a URL in the standard form, actually.

Comment: I think they mean they want the direct link, which Flickr does not always allow.

Comment: @Arkascha from what they've sound, it sounds like they want to be able to show the image on a website via the img tag, however doing what you've posted doesn't show the image, it just shows the broken image error. :p - It's also a pretty badly worded question.

Comment: @LaimMcKenzie I have no idea if that URL resolves to a valid image resource. But again: that is not what is asked. It indeed might be that the service provider blocks such requests. That is up to him. But that has nothing to do with how a `<img>` tag is used. That would be a question of usage terms and protections.

Comment: I want to get the image shown in a web site. However, I have only the URL. Is it possible?

Comment: @ILIAS As said before: An image _always_ is loaded via a URL. That is how http works. A "path" is worthless for that.

Comment: All has been said here. I vote to close this question. @ILIAS Please read about how http and the `<img>` tag work and are used. You are expected to understand those basics.